# Android and HTTPS Web Service (XmlPullParserException)

Tags: android, web-services

I've looked around at several different questions/answers here on SO regarding the XmlPullParserException in Android using KSOAP2 but so far nothing has helped me figure out what's wrong. I'm starting to port over my iOS App to Android, and right now I'm stuck on this part of getting the app to communicate with a .Net Web Service. Below is the code in question, most of which was pieced together from various different questions/blogs/sites since I also have a self signed certificate on the Web Service. If anyone has any tips or can point me in the direction of some reading that will help me figure this out that would be great since there are several other areas of the app the use the Web Service and I know I'm going to need to know how to debug this better than what I'm getting now.

```
String URL = "https://online.ensinet.com/Services/ENSIMobileservice.asmx";
            String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ensinet.com/VerifyRep";
            String NAMESPACE = "http://ensinet.com/";
            String METHOD_NAME = "VerifyRep";
            String SERVER = "online.ensinet.com";

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            //PropertyInfo usernamePI = new PropertyInfo();
            //usernamePI.setName("RepLogin");
            //usernamePI.setValue(username);
            //usernamePI.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty("RepLogin", username);

            //PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
            //passPI.setName("RepPass");
            //passPI.setValue(passphrase);
            //passPI.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty("RepPass",passphrase);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            try
            {
                allowAllSSL();
                HttpsTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpsTransportSE(SERVER,443, URL, 1000);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);  
                SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            Log.i("Message", "the response contains: " + response.toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("Message", "there was an error: " + e);
            }
```

Okay so here's a little bit more information. First the allowAllSSL() is a method I found in another forum to bypass the credential manager of a self signed certificate since I don't have the credentials and the information that is being gathered by the mobile device isn't sensitive like the Web Application where all the Web Services are hosted. Below is the method in detail that sets up a fake credential manager

```
    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;

public static class _FakeX509TrustManager implements
        javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[] {};

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return (true);
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return (true);
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return (_AcceptedIssuers);
    }
}

public static void allowAllSSL() {

    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

    javax.net.ssl.SSLContext context = null;

    if (trustManagers == null) {
        trustManagers = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] { new _FakeX509TrustManager() };
    }

    try {
        context = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
    }
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
            .getSocketFactory());
}
}
```

Also, I took a look at the requestDump and I noticed that in the request there's a `<Header />` tag that isn't part of the actual Web Service request so I think this is being added by KSOAP2, and so far I haven't seen a way to remove it which may be part of the START TAG erro that I'm getting. I think I'm going to have the build the SOAP request manually, which I will try later tonight to see if that works.

Comment: Post full stack trace. `allowAllSSL()` sound very suspicious, what does it do? Post code. Generally, if you have a self-signed certificate you should set up the app to trust it, allowing _any_ certificate is a _bad idea_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was able to figure out the problem. It looks like the android side is a bit more specific than the iOS side since the problem was the URL that I was using. In the code above I was using the URL of the complete list of Operations that are available for the Mobile Application like in the iOS code, but I needed to use the actual URL of the Operation I was calling (so I needed to add ?op=VerifyRep to the end of the URL string above). Now I'm getting the right responses, so it's off to the next step and trying to figure out how the parse out the data needed.